# Allowing not entered data using query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

User enters two data, which is an interval period, and is stored as INT in database.
Suppose i have following data :

```
Table :cheque_book_mcg

id   acc_no  cheq_bk_no cheq_no_frm cheq_no_to sch_id no_from       no_to
401 010000001 285      01029101     01029125    010   29101        29125
402 001000467 277      00130326     00130350    001   30326        30350
403 001000467 54       00122252     00122275    001   22252        22275
404 001000467 1149     00167551     00167575    001   67551        67575
405 003000016 45       00322301     00322325    003   22301        22325
406 001000468 46       00122326     00122350    001   22326        22350
407 001000470 335      00122401     00122425    001   22401        22425
408 001000471 848      00164651     00164675    001   64651        64675
409 001000471 1346     00145476     00145500    001   45476        45500
```

User can enter the interval (no_from and no_to) as desired, which is not a duplicate entry.
Such that , in the present context, user can enter (no_from = 1 and no_to = 10) and then if
the user enters (21 and 30) it must also be valid, and also there is an interval gap between, so afterwards if the user wants to add data from (11 and 20), it should be valid, Referring to the above entered data , user can also enter the remaining interval, in above table the highest interval is (67551 and 67575), so the user can also enter the interval starting from (67576 and so on....), also the user can enter the intervals lower than the above entered intervals as well as missing intervals between the entered data. But should not repeat, the interval. I have written a query as follows :

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN ((select MAX(id) from cheque_book_mcg WHERE no_to < 1) = (select MIN(id) from cheque_book_mcg WHERE no_from <= 20))
THEN
'yes'
ELSE
'no'
END as valid
```

This works for entering the interval in between the data available in the table, but does not work for lower interval lower than the previously entered interval and does not work for higher interval higher than the previously entered interval.

How to achieve this goal ??

Comment: Do you want to prevent any overlapping ranges? So if you a range (1,20) exists, the range (11,30) should be refused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it by `exists()` condition for range which you want to check like

```
if exists( select id from cheque_book_mcg 
           where ((@from_no between no_from and no_to) 
           or (@to_no between no_from and no_to)))
print 'no' -- already range exists, don't insert
else
print 'yes' -- no any range, can insert
```

Using `CASE WHEN` clause like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN exists( select id from cheque_book_mcg 
                         where ((@from_no between no_from and no_to) 
                         or (@to_no between no_from and no_to)))
            THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END as Valid
```

Comment: I will try and reply.

Comment: I think it worked but the thing is that I need to return the value 'yes' or 'no' to java code, can 'print' be mapped to java code ??

Comment: You can return 'yes' or 'no' or any 1 or 0 value instead of print. Are you using stored procedure ? If there is stored procedure then save yes/no value in any variable and then return it

Comment: No, I am not using stored procedure. Like the query I have posted, I can track the result by using ResultSet.getString(1), Is it possible for 'print' ?

Comment: Check my updated answer with CASE WHEN.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger like this will prevent the insertion of overlapping cheque number ranges for a given account number:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PreventOverlappingChequeNumbers ON cheque_book_mcg 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM cheque_book_mcg cbm
        INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON ((cbm.no_from <= I.no_to AND i.no_from <= cbm.no_from)
        AND cbm.acc_no = i.acc_no))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Cheque number ranges may not overlap', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK
    END
END
```